# Prioritize "Buy Now" Button Image

Tags: e-commerce

Today, while testing my website on a connection slower than my usual work connection, I noticed that the Chrome was downloading a bunch of other images on my product detail page before downloading the "Buy Now" button image. This is a problem because without the buy now button, there is no way to actually add the product to your shopping cart.

I'm looking for a way to force the browser to download the image for the button first, before any other images. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

you could set your images to display:none then turn them back to inline with javascript after the page loads, starting with the paypal image...

Comment: Will that make it load first - or just hide the others until the buy now image loads?

Comment: if the display is none the browser won't try to render the images, so it should accomplish what you want i.e. it will download the paynow image first, then the other ones as you change the "display" value